Python list with NumPy arrays as elements
I have a list with NumPy arrays as elements that looks like this:
[array([ 0.2, -2.3,  5.3]),
 array([-1.6, -1.7,  0.3]),
 array([ 2.4, -0.2, -3.0]),
 array([-4.1, -2.3, -2.7])]

and I want to convert it into 3 lists, each with elements from the columns of the above list. So the desired outcome looks like
list1 = [0.2, -1.6, 2.4, -4.1]
list2 = [-2.3, -1.7, -0.2, -2.3]
list3 = [5.3, 0.3, -3.0, -2.7]


Does the result really need to be lists?  would tuples be ok?  And what about the list elements - python floats, or would np.float be ok?  In numpy2 they display differently.  Answers using tolist() will make a more thorough conversion to python floats.

You can achieve this by using NumPy's transpose or T method like this:
transposed = np.array(array_list).T
list1, list2, list3 = transposed.tolist()


Full example

You can use zip
a = [
    np.array([0.2, -2.3, 5.3]),
    np.array([-1.6, -1.7, 0.3]),
    np.array([2.4, -0.2, -3.0]),
    np.array([-4.1, -2.3, -2.7])
]

With list comp in one line using zip:
list1,list2,list3 = [list(x) for x in zip(*a)]


which can be simplified to list1,list2,list3 = zip(*a).  Rightside unpacking iterates through the zip.  Unless the OP really needs lists instead of tuples.

@hpaulj yes, absolutely. Op will get 3 tuples.

Assuming your list of arrays has been defined as follows:
import numpy as np

array_list = [np.array([ 0.2, -2.3,  5.3]),
              np.array([-1.6, -1.7,  0.3]),
              np.array([ 2.4, -0.2, -3.0]),
              np.array([-4.1, -2.3, -2.7])]

Then you can use the following one-liner:
list1, list2, list3 = np.transpose(array_list).tolist()

NumPy's transpose() function will implicitly convert array_list into a two-dimensional NumPy array (so no need to do this explicitly) before transposing it (i.e. turning rows into columns and columns into rows). Calling tolist() on the resulting array will turn it into a list of lists, with three elements (corresponding to the original three columns) on the topmost level. Assigning the result with list1, list2, list3 = ... will "unpack" this three-element list into the three target variables.
If you are fine with the results (list1, list2, list3) being again NumPy arrays rather than lists, you can omit tolist(), thus only writing:
list1, list2, list3 = np.transpose(array_list)


you can try
import numpy as np

a = [
    np.array([0.2, -2.3, 5.3]),
    np.array([-1.6, -1.7, 0.3]),
    np.array([2.4, -0.2, -3.0]),
    np.array([-4.1, -2.3, -2.7])
]

list1 = [arr[0] for arr in a]
list2 = [arr[1] for arr in a]
list3 = [arr[2] for arr in a]

# your result
print("list1:", list1)
print("list2:", list2)
print("list3:", list3)


You could stack the list into a 2D numpy array and transpose it.
import numpy as np


array_list = [np.array([0.2, -2.3, 5.3]),
              np.array([-1.6, -1.7, 0.3]),
              np.array([2.4, -0.2, -3.0]),
              np.array([-4.1, -2.3, -2.7])]


stacked_array = np.vstack(array_list).T


list1, list2, list3 = stacked_array[0].tolist(), stacked_array[1].tolist(), stacked_array[2].tolist()

print(list1) print(list2) print(list3)

